# PHP combine two preg_replace into one for email and phone hiding

Tags: php

I got the email and phone to be hidden individually. How can I get the two combined so that I can run a check on one string and if email and/or phone are found the replace them.

```
$string= 'text text example@domain.com blalba blalba blalba 777 777 7777 blalba blalba';

$hide_email = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/', '[hide email]', $string);
$hide_phone = preg_replace('/[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\-\s]*\d{3}[.\-\s]*\d{4}/', '[hide phone]', $string);

echo $string; //hide the email and/or phone found
```

Comment: Anything particularly wrong with 2 calls? (not to mention `preg_replace` accepts an array of regular expressions)

Comment: I guess nothing is wrong but how can I echo variable that contains the whole string with the hidden email/phone ?

Comment: you just apply second `preg_replace` not to the original string but to...

Answer (score 0):

Copy and pasted your code above.

```
$string= 'text text example@domain.com blalba blalba blalba 777 777 7777 blalba blalba';
```

$string = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/', '[hide email]', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.-\s]*\d{3}[.-\s]*\d{4}/', '[hide phone]', $string);

echo $string; //hide the email and/or phone found